# OrientDB corruption state in Nexus Repository version 3.2.0-01

Tags: nexus, orientdb, nexus3

We are using Nexus Repository version 3.2.0-01 and started getting the following error in nexus.log. OrientDB has got corrupted. Nexus is no longer starting.

```html
2017-03-21 13:00:36,329+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl - OrientDB version: 2.2.13
2017-03-21 13:00:36,348+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer - OrientDB Server v2.2.13 is starting up...
2017-03-21 13:00:36,355+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer - Databases directory: /c9/setup/apps/nexus/sonatype-work/nexus3/db
2017-03-21 13:00:36,647+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies - Not enough physical memory available for DISKCACHE: 1,873MB (heap=1,161MB direct=2,048MB). Set lower Maximum Heap (-Xmx setting on JVM) and restart OrientDB. Now running with DISKCACHE=256MB
2017-03-21 13:00:36,648+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies - OrientDB config DISKCACHE=256MB (heap=1,161MB direct=2,048MB os=1,873MB)
2017-03-21 13:00:36,735+0000 WARN  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer - Found ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD variable, using this value as root's password
2017-03-21 13:00:36,899+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.handler.OJMXPlugin - JMX plugin installed and active: 

profilerManaged=true
2017-03-21 13:00:36,901+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer - OrientDB Studio available at $ANSI{blue 

http://localhost:2480/studio/index.html}
2017-03-21 13:00:36,902+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.OServer - $ANSI{green:italic OrientDB Server is active} v2.2.13.
2017-03-21 13:00:36,902+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl - Activated
2017-03-21 13:00:36,904+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager - Start UPGRADE
2017-03-21 13:00:37,632+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseInstanceImpl - Lifecycle operation start failed
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSecurityAccessException: User or password not valid for database: 'config'^M
        DB name="config"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OSecurityShared.authenticate(OSecurityShared.java:237) [na:na]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OSecurityShared.authenticate(OSecurityShared.java:237) [na:na]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OSecurityExternal.authenticate(OSecurityExternal.java:62) [na:na]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.security.OSecurityProxy.authenticate(OSecurityProxy.java:107) [na:na]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:274) [na:na]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseManagerSupport.connect(DatabaseManagerSupport.java:142) [org.sonatype.nexus.orient:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseInstanceImpl.doStart(DatabaseInstanceImpl.java:56) [na:na]
        at org.sonatype.goodies.lifecycle.LifecycleSupport.start(LifecycleSupport.java:104) [org.sonatype.goodies.lifecycle:2.2.3]
        at org.sonatype.goodies.lifecycle.Lifecycles.start(Lifecycles.java:44) [org.sonatype.goodies.lifecycle:2.2.3]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseManagerSupport.createInstance(DatabaseManagerSupport.java:258) [org.sonatype.nexus.orient:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseManagerSupport.instance(DatabaseManagerSupport.java:232) [org.sonatype.nexus.orient:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.ConfigDatabase$ProviderImpl.get(ConfigDatabase.java:61) [org.sonatype.nexus.base:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.ConfigDatabase$ProviderImpl.get(ConfigDatabase.java:1) [org.sonatype.nexus.base:3.2.0.01]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1019) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
         at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81) [org.eclipse.sisu.inject:0.3.2]
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.BeanProviders.firstOf(BeanProviders.java:179) [org.eclipse.sisu.inject:0.3.2]
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.PlaceholderBeanProvider.lookup(PlaceholderBeanProvider.java:122) [org.eclipse.sisu.inject:0.3.2]
        at org.eclipse.sisu.wire.PlaceholderBeanProvider.get(PlaceholderBeanProvider.java:90) [org.eclipse.sisu.inject:0.3.2]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176) [org.eclipse.sisu.inject:0.3.2]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1019) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1085) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1015) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.ModelVersionStore.doStart(ModelVersionStore.java:82) [org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuardLifecycleSupport.start(StateGuardLifecycleSupport.java:67) [org.sonatype.nexus.common:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.ModelVersionStore$$EnhancerByGuice$$b30c182f.CGLIB$start$5(<generated>) [3.2.0-01:na]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.ModelVersionStore$$EnhancerByGuice$$b30c182f$$FastClassByGuice$$94ba58c4.invoke(<generated>) [3.2.0-01:na]
        at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.$MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:76) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.MethodInvocationAction.run(MethodInvocationAction.java:39) [org.sonatype.nexus.common:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.StateGuard$TransitionImpl.run(StateGuard.java:191) [org.sonatype.nexus.common:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.common.stateguard.TransitionsInterceptor.invoke(TransitionsInterceptor.java:56) [org.sonatype.nexus.common:3.2.0.01]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:77) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:55) [com.google.inject:4.1.0]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.ModelVersionStore$$EnhancerByGuice$$b30c182f.start(<generated>) [3.2.0-01:na]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade.internal.UpgradeServiceImpl.doStart(UpgradeServiceImpl.java:80) [org.sonatype.nexus.upgrade:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.goodies.lifecycle.LifecycleSupport.start(LifecycleSupport.java:104) [org.sonatype.goodies.lifecycle:2.2.3]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.startComponent(NexusLifecycleManager.java:154) [org.sonatype.nexus.extender:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager.to(NexusLifecycleManager.java:94) [org.sonatype.nexus.extender:3.2.0.01]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener.frameworkEvent(NexusContextListener.java:185) [org.sonatype.nexus.extender:3.2.0.01]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1429) [org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308) [org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

**Root cause**
Root cause of this was found to be an unclean shutdown of Nexus because of disk space getting full, this resulted in DB corruption.

```html
2017-03-17 07:09:49,480+0000 WARN  [elasticsearch[A82A95AC-5D396A2B-337B8736-5017E8FC-915232E4][local_transport][T#1]] *SYSTEM org.elasticsearch.cluster.action.shard - [A82A95AC-5D396A2B-337B8736-5017E8FC-915232E4] [cab22f445c1892acef64d17ac2da6d0086023e21][0] received shard failed for [cab22f445c1892acef64d17ac2da6d0086023e21][0], node[HBjARpI7RyqqqruVqEJ8Ig], [P], v[11], s[INITIALIZING], a[id=FmxOHS7nQcGNz_93VlTpKg], unassigned_info[[reason=ALLOCATION_FAILED], at[2017-03-17T07:09:49.101Z], details[failed recovery, failure IndexShardRecoveryException[failed to recovery from gateway]; nested: EngineCreationFailureException[failed to recover from translog]; nested: EngineException[failed to recover from translog]; nested: IndexFailedEngineException[Index failed for [component#36e3dec8de528c9b41c5c6ac3b18e3f7]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[No space left on device]; ]], indexUUID [fLN4hdE8QPKH7Pj5RpLtmw], message [engine failure, reason [index]], failure [NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[No space left on device]]
org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.NotSerializableExceptionWrapper: No space left on device
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(FileDispatcherImpl.java:60) [na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) [na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) [na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:211) [na:1.8.0_121]
at org.elasticsearch.common.io.Channels.writeToChannel(Channels.java:211) [na:na]
at org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.PagedBytesReference.writeTo(PagedBytesReference.java:132) [na:na]
at org.elasticsearch.index.translog.BufferingTranslogWriter.add(BufferingTranslogWriter.java:57) [na:na]
```

**No backup** 
We have not backed up Nexus VM, therefore we wont be able to restore it back. What is the possible way out - recreating the database - with least damage. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 39):

Just in case that actually matters for somebody else - the above did not help me, but the json export / import one.

In my case nexus runs in the official docker image, so

```
docker exec -it nexus bash
```

Or however you access your nexus shell

```
cd /tmp
/opt/jdk1.8.0_141/bin/java -jar /opt/sonatype/nexus/lib/support/nexus-orient-console.jar

CONNECT plocal:/nexus-data/db/component admin admin

export database component-export
drop database
create database plocal:/nexus-data/db/component
import database component-export.json.gz
```

In your case the java-path could vary as also the data-path (nexus data) which we use to connect/create the database.

After that, restarting the service and your component database should be up and running again

Comment: I had to use `CREATE DATABASE PLOCAL:/usr/local/orientdb/databases/demo` to create a database

Comment: thanky very much for sharing, worked for me as well. solved the same corruption issue with component caused by full disk. also +1 @Markus, had to prefix `plocal:` as well, else I got `incorrelt url` exception

Answer (score 29):

We had similar issue with Nexus OSS verison 3.2.0-01 and OrientDB corrupted state because of unclean shutdown.

In our case the corrupted storage was **component** located in

`$install-dir/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/component`

```
2017-04-14 15:09:20,007+0200 ERROR [qtp18266400-74] *UNKNOWN com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.reentrant - Could not dispatch event AssetUpdatedEvent{metadata=AttachedEntityMetadata{schema=asset, document=asset#18:91856{bucket:#13:3,format:maven2,last_updated:Fri Apr 14 15:09:19 CEST 2017,attributes:[5],component:null,name:org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/maven-metadata.xml,size:743,content_type:application/xml,blob_ref:default@ECF4439E-D7F184F8-578BAB14-ACFC0FB8-5589B163:3fb95745-4aed-460f-b711-b5f5b74b837c,last_accessed:Fri Apr 14 15:09:19 CEST 2017} v466}, remoteNodeId=null} to subscriber org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.internal.group.MavenGroupFacet$$EnhancerByGuice$$a88d7327@83eca7 method [public void org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.internal.group.MavenGroupFacet.on(org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.AssetEvent)]
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Error during transaction commit
        DB name="component"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.makeRollback(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:2210) [na:na]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.commit(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1433) [na:na]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.doCommit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:539) [com.orientechnologies.orientdb-core:2.2.13]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.commit(OTransactionOptimistic.java:104) [com.orientechnologies.orientdb-core:2.2.13]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2756) [com.orientechnologies.orientdb-core:2.2.13]
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.commit(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2725) [com.orientechnologies.orientdb-core:2.2.13]
        at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageTxImpl.commit(StorageTxImpl.java:172) [org.sonatype.nexus.repository:3.2.0.01]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source) [na:na]
```

---

#### We managed to solve our problem with the following strategy

1. Scheduling Nexus tasks, particullary:

   - Rebuild Maven repository metadata.
   - Rebuild repository index.
   - Compact blob store.
2. Orient DB manipulation:

   - Rebuilding indexes.
   - Repairing database.

According Nexus support you can access Orient DB console with **Nexus OSS verison 3.2.1-01**. Everything is explained [here](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002930827-Accessing-the-OrientDB-Console). Make sure your Nexus application is properly shut down before you apply any operations on database.

Once in Orient DB console you connect to local database with

```
> CONNECT PLOCAL:${your_install_dir}/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/${database} admin admin
```

And you perform the following operations:

```
> REBUILD INDEX *
> REPAIR DATABASE --fix-graph
> REPAIR DATABASE --fix-links
> REPAIR DATABASE --fix-ridbags
> REPAIR DATABASE --fix-bonsai
> DISCONNECT
```

I am absolutely aware my answer probably won't solve your concrete problem but I still wanted to give you some directions because you don't have any backups.

Comment: In our case when we ran out of space the wal files were corrupted, and we weren't able to connect to the databases from the orient DB console.

Comment: For me, this seemed to work at first, but pushing still gave a 500. Had to restore from backup in the end

Comment: this didnt work for me it was too currupt, followed this one  with an export import and it worked fine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951710/orientdb-corruption-state-in-nexus-repository-version-3-2-0-01/45986526#45986526

Answer (score 13):

The database write ahead logs are corrupt.

Make a backup of `$install-dir/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/component`, and then remove files with extension `.wal` from that directory.  Then try the startup again

if the issue still persist, try clearing all `.wal` files under the "DB" directory, will resolve the issue,

I did tried this method and it worked like charm.

regards
vinay

Answer (score 13):

I had the same mistake:

> Cannot open local storage '/nexus-data/db/config' with mode=rw

and when starting the nexus console (`java -jar /opt/sonatype/nexus/lib/support/nexus-orient-console.jar`)  the following message appeared:

> [image]

The reason was that Nexus was out of memory and had created some ".wal" files with 0 bytes in the folder "/nexus-data/db/config/". After I deleted them, everything worked again.

Many thanks also to yobert https://gist.github.com/marcelmaatkamp/123e8793e07a72a382d8d0e8d66bbd8f

Comment: Deleting both the db/config/*.wal files and the db/component/*.wal files fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

With Nexus 3.16 there is now a task:
 **Create Repair - Reconcile component database from blob store**

super slow, but it helps recreating a accidentally deleted blobstore still on disk.

Comment: That helped me restore some information in the DB, but before, I had to bring it to a minimal usable state, and only the export/create/import cycle helped me achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the cache folder (/opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/cache) solved the issue for me

Comment: If you are like me, just doing a new installation, I think this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the file `frozen.marker` from the db folder solved it for us.