# Cannot open local storage '/opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/config' with mode=rw

Tags: orientdb, nexus

I am upgrading the nexus to 3.22.0 in my ubuntu machine. For that i have followed this guide "https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/installation/run-as-a-service". Nexus is running locally with nexus user, but when I check the ui getting 502 bad gateway error and in logs i found this. Please help on this.

```html
2020-04-15 04:20:48,643+0000 ERROR [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM Felix - Framework listener delivery error.
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/opt/sonatype-work/nexus3/db/config' with mode=rw
        DB name="config"
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.open(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:323)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:259)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseManagerSupport.connect(DatabaseManagerSupport.java:178)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseManagerSupport.createInstance(DatabaseManagerSupport.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
        at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.DatabaseManagerSupport.instance(DatabaseManagerSupport.java:289)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.wal.ODiskWriteAheadLog.cutTill(ODiskWriteAheadLog.java:919)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.makeFullCheckpoint(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3706)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.recoverIfNeeded(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:3937)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.open(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:288)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
2020-04-15 04:20:48,671+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusContextListener - Uptime: 22 seconds and 114 milliseconds (nexus-oss-edition/3.22.0.02)
2020-04-15 04:20:48,672+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager - Shutting down
2020-04-15 04:20:48,673+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager - Stop STORAGE
2020-04-15 04:20:48,676+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl$1 - OrientDB Server is shutting down...
2020-04-15 04:20:48,676+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl$1 - Shutting down protocols
2020-04-15 04:20:48,676+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager - Shutting down plugins:
2020-04-15 04:20:48,676+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.server.plugin.OServerPluginManager - - jmx
2020-04-15 04:20:48,677+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl$1 - OrientDB Server shutdown complete
2020-04-15 04:20:48,677+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - Orient Engine is shutting down...
2020-04-15 04:20:48,678+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - - shutdown storage: component...
2020-04-15 04:20:48,700+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - - shutdown storage: config...
2020-04-15 04:20:48,700+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - - shutdown storage: OSystem...
2020-04-15 04:20:49,312+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM com.orientechnologies.orient.core.Orient - OrientDB Engine shutdown complete
2020-04-15 04:20:49,313+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.internal.orient.DatabaseServerImpl - Shutdown
2020-04-15 04:20:49,313+0000 INFO  [FelixStartLevel]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.extender.NexusLifecycleManager - Stop KERNEL
```

Comment: Look in the $workdir/db directory... is there a “frozen.marker” file?  If so, this means the instance was shut down while a backup was running.  Remove that file.

Comment: I removed that frozen.marker file and re-started the nexus, didn't work.

Comment: Same error after removal?

Comment: Yes, same error

Comment: I had the same issue and i've found a workaround. Please see my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42951710/orientdb-corruption-state-in-nexus-repository-version-3-2-0-01/64694957#64694957

Answer (score 0):

In my case, followed an tutorial that wasn't mention the folder on the *./sonatype-work/* was an folder outside of the nexus application, and then was causing an issue related to permissions. i left the **`/opt/nexus/bin/nexus.vmoptions`** as it is, with **../sonatype-work/** [Attention on the 2 dots], and then reboot the entire machine, and then the permissions problem was solved.

PS: i started an 1st run with nexus user, and took almost 1 hour to the environment be setup on an 8 cores 12gb ram machine. the DB related thing, took too much time, but works!

2 PS: use this file as an example for the nexus.vmoptions that may help you.

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1024m

-XX:LogFile=../sonatype-work/nexus3/log/jvm.log
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dkaraf.home=.
-Dkaraf.base=.
-Dkaraf.etc=etc/karaf
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/etc/karaf/java.util.logging.properties
-Dkaraf.data=../sonatype-work/nexus3
-Dkaraf.log=../sonatype-work/nexus3/log
-Djava.io.tmpdir=../sonatype-work/nexus3/tmp
```